# Change commit message with an npm script

Tags: git, npm, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I currently have the `pre-commit` package in my `package.json` file.
What I'm trying to do now is to add a new npm script that alters the commit message.

More specifically I'd like the commit message to be prepended with the current branch name. For example:

```
git commit -m "fix some bug"
```

would be translated in something like

```
FEATURE123: fix some bug
```